# Have a friendly WCF published service name

Tags: wcf

How can I change the name of the WCF web service, once I published the solution I get the same name that I have in:

```
<services>   
    <service name="WcfService.Data.Service.MyWcf">
```

I tried to update the name in the service tag but then I get an error, WCF can't find any metadata.

Any ideas?

I want the published svc file be with only "MyWcf.svc"

Comment: You cannot do that - the service name **must be** the fully qualified name of the class that implements the service

Comment: The service name is the implementation class of the service interface, you can not modify it at will.